# A functional equation problem with an interesting pattern

Tags: induction, functional-equations

> PROBLEM STATEMENT:

Let $ f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be a function defined by $$ f(1)=2, \ f(2)=1, \ \ f(3n)=3f(n), \ f(3n+1)=3f(n)+2,  \ f(3n+2)=3f(n)+1 $$

Find the number of $n≤2001$ for which $f(n)=2n$.

> MY PROGRESS:

I could easily figure out that the answer is $2^7 - 1=127$.

Evaluating $f(n)$ for small values of $n$, I found an interesting pattern:

> First write the natural number $n$ in base 3 representation. Then to obtain $f(n)$, replace 2 by 1 and 1 by 2 in the base 3 representation obtained earlier. Finally convert the base 3 string in decimal system to get $f(n)$.

Examples:

$f(5)=8 : (5)_{10}= (12)_{3} \Rightarrow f(5)= (21)_{3} = (8)_{10}  $

$f(11)=19 : (11)_{10}= (102)_{3} \Rightarrow f(11)=(201)_{3} = (19)_{10}$

Now, to prove the claim I am using induction. Inspired from one of the problem of the similar kind, I decided to use induction on $m$, the number of digits of $n$ in base 3 representation.

> > Suppose the result is true for every natural number $n$ such that the number of digits in the base 3 representation of $n$ is less than or equal to $m$. Now take any natural number $n$ whose base 3 representation consists of $m+1$ digits.

I am stuck here. How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: May I know why someone down voted the question? Earlier it had 2 votes. (Assuming that the person who voted didn't take back his vote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the numbers used below are base 3.
Also, if $k=1021$ and $m=1221$, $\overline{km}=10211221$.

We are given:

$$f(\overline{k0})=\overline{f(k)0}$$
$$f(\overline{k1})=\overline{f(k)2}$$
$$f(\overline{k2})=\overline{f(k)1}$$

Now, in order to find $f(n)$, we use these equations on $n$ from right to left.

For example, $n=1021$:

$$f(1021)=\overline{f(102)2}=\overline{f(10)12}=\overline{f(1)012}=2012$$

Comment: Nice solution. But does this uses induction or you have given an idea on how to approach using induction?

Comment: My last line is actually based on induction. To make this proof rigorous, we can write: if $f(n)$ follows the pattern, then $f(3n), f(3n+1), f(3n+2)$ follow the pattern as well. @AbVk1718